# How to interface JSON data and display table

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, jira-rest-api

So I am trying to display a list of devices from the database into an angular material table. I've written the REST api for it which is something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');

//parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//create database connection
const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'project'
});

//connect to database
conn.connect((err) =>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log('Mysql connected....');
});

//server listening
app.listen(3000,() =>{
  console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

//show login page
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/dashboard'))
app.get('/',(req,res) => {
  res.send('Use /api/devices');
});

//show all devices
app.get('/api/devices',(req,res) => {
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM tempstatus";
  let query = conn.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(JSON.stringify({'status': 200, 'error': null, 'response': results}));
  });
});
```

And now I have written a controller as follows:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [require('angular-material-data-table')]);

myApp.controller('DeviceController', function($scope, $http){
    console.log('DeviceController loaded')
    $scope.getDevices = function(){
        var device = null;
        $http.get('/api/devices').success(function(response) {
            device = response;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm rather new to Angular and nodejs and I don't really know how what else I must do and how to display the data I get in an angular material table. Can you please help me out?

This is the JSON data I'm getting from the API:

```
"status":200,"error":null,"response": {"serialnum":"0","time":"2020-02-11T12:36:27.000Z","type":"","temparature":"","date":"2020-02-10T18:30:00.000Z","status":"not active","comments":""}
```

And this is the angular.module.ts file. As I said, I'm new to angular and I don't know how to write my code. So far I've only done this and the controller in angular:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you provide some Angular code so we can help you ?

Comment: Add your snippet of code by editing your post please :)